# Trigger insert on the same table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table that look like that :

```
table t1 (
id INT autoincremente,
numero VARCHAR
)
```

I need to set the value of numero = prefix + id when there is an insert.

So I tryed to that using a trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `mySweetTrigger`
AFTER INSERT ON `t1`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.numero = CONCAT('prefix', NEW.id);
END
```

But can't make it work...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just on a sidenode. Why would you want to have a column identical to your id, only with a prefix. Why not getting this with `SELECT id, CONCAT('prefix', id) AS numero FROM ... ` when selecting, or when prefixes differ, only store prefix and concat when accessing the data

Answer (score 1):

The after insert trigger is not allowed to modify it's own data. The before insert does not have the auto increment value available. So that looks like a problem.

Luckily you can access the auto increment value from the schema.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `mySweetTrigger`
BEFORE INSERT ON `t1`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.numero = CONCAT('prefix', 
      (
        SELECT 
          AUTO_INCREMENT 
        FROM information_schema.TABLES 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='t1'
      ));
END
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine with 1 line insert. 

However, when I insert multiple lines, the AUTO_INCREMENT value isn't correct...